# Android - can not access the html file on sdCard

Tags: android, html, browser

I am trying to open html file that I have on my sdCard in Chrome or any other web browser (not html Viewer).

I have tried to enter path to file like this

```
 file:///storage/extSdCard/page/page.html
```

I get this error:

```
 ERR_ACCESS_DENIED
```

What could be wrong please?

EDIT: I have to mention that I am not developing a android app. I just want to view a html file, that is on my SD card in chrome mobile browser

EDIT2: It is not working from ext. sdcard and also from internal memory

Thank you.

Comment: I think your HTML file is corrupted. i mean is not proper formatted or not created properly. check the size first

Comment: Do you have the permission to read external sdCard in your manifest? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is simply happening because the chrome app doesn't have the permission to read the external storage.
if you need such an app [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.ne.shira.html.viewer) is a link.
Here is a list of *chrome app permissions*....

**Your accounts**

- find accounts on the device
- add or remove accounts
- use accounts on the device
- read Google service configuration

**Your location**

- approximate location (network-based)
- precise location (GPS and network-based)

**Network communication**

- view network connections
- control Near Field Communication
- receive data from Internet
- full network access

**Storage**

- modify or delete the contents of your USB storage

**System tools**

- test access to protected storage
- install shortcuts

**Bookmarks and History**

- write web bookmarks and history
- read your Web bookmarks and history

**Camera**

- take pictures and videos

**Microphone**

- record audio

**Affects battery**

- prevent device from sleeping
- control vibration

**Audio settings**

- change your audio settings

**Sync Settings**

- read sync statistics
- toggle sync on and off
- read sync settings

Comment: and is there any possibility to view my html in something else than html viewer? If not, does html viewer has allowed JS please?

Answer (score 2):

One way to work around was (on a device with a side loaded chrome)

```
adb shell pm grant com.chrome.canary android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

"com.android.chrome" might be the name if you aren't using canary version of chrome.

Comment: This works to an extent, but .html files still cannot be accessed.

Answer (score 1):

Upload your html files into any app's internal file directory. I added my file to default browser app's directory.

And type the following url in your browser:

```
file:///storage/sdcard/Android/data/com.android.browser/files/yourfile.html
```

It should be successfully rendering the web page.

Answer (score 1):

As stated, Google doesn´t have permissions to access the file.

However other browsers will get you there without an issue. It works for me using Opera on my Android smartphone and using this as URL:

```
file:///storage/emulated/0/{folder-where-your-file-is}/file.html
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and indeed Chrome can't access files from external storage. If you don't want to root your phone or move the html html file to internal storage, just use another browser with the required permissions, like Firefox. At least that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the only way I found to solve the problem of reading the html file in Chrome in a device that isn't rooted is to copy or move the html file into the device's internal memory storage.

The alternative is to root the device and change the permissions to allow sdCard access in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do the same for my own website. I did not want to look up my website on the internet, because I would get charged by google adwords for clicking on it. 
I copied the files of my website (index.html and all the folders) to the Internal Storage Download folder, in a folder mywebsite.com that I created.
In the Chrome browser, I typed the following:

```
file://com.estrongs.files/storage/emulated/0/Download/mywebsite.com/index.html
```

The website opened up perfectly with all the linked pages and images.
I then bookmarked it as a favorite so I don't have to type the long url again.
The directory structure I show is on my Samsung Android phone. It may be different on another android or iphone. The key is that the website files need to be on internal storage and not on the SD Card as Chrome does not have permission to access external storage.