# How can I open local external data card html files in the any Android browser?

Tags: android, html, google-chrome

I am able to access internal storage details files (my case I am looking for html files) in chrome using file:///sdcard it works. 
But I am not able to access files presents in external data card. I had tried giving all possible rights to chrome browser but no luck ERR_ACCESS_DENIED if I try file:///.

My problem is i have very limited space on internal storage so cant move all data to internal storage.

I looked for different sites http://forums.androidcentral.com/ask-question/444838-how-do-i-reference-open-html-file-external-sd-card.html

Comment: It is unclear what you are doing and what you want. You did not even tell where and how you used "file://<path>". How do you start Chrome by the way?

Comment: I wants to access or view some local video files from external data card which can be accessed from one central html file which contains all these video links or links pointing to these videos usually resides under same folder or same parent folder. (as already explained it works for in files in internal data storage and path used file:///sdcard)

Comment: You could as well give one example of such a link.

Comment: It is only Chrome that pretents that permissions are failing. But HtmlViewers or FireFox will just display from any path. I think the rest of the common browsers will do it too as there is no reason to not be able to display from SD card.

Comment: This is not a Chrome Apps question.

Comment: Thanks GreenApps htmlviewer worked for me, only issue the htmlviewer is that it doesn't opens mp4 video files directly.. but I am managed to open it from ahref links from other html page and it worked. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21675758/android-can-not-access-the-html-file-on-sdcard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    if (!Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
        Log.d(TAG, "No SDCARD");
    } else {
        webComp.loadUrl("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/packagename/files/something.html");
    }
```

UPDATE

webComp is an instance of WebView where you can pass your file path in the .loadUrl("path_of_your_file") method and it will show your data to Webview.
if you want to use from local storage you have to add file:// before file path as shown in example.

Comment: Is there any way to find Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() directory name for non android developer.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.